# How do I get GitHub to not show organization's updates on my timeline

Tags: github

I was recently added to an organization on GitHub and consequently, and updates that anyone makes to a repository on the organization are displayed on my timeline. Is there any way to suppress these updates?

Answer (score 0):

By contacting GitHub support, apparently it is not possible to unfollow an entire organization's repositories at once. However, one can unwatch the repositories one by one. Such a tedious task but solves the issue.